# FancyBox image loading trigger error

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox, fancybox-2

On [this site](http://maillouxdumontet.com/fr/liste-des-proprietes.php) when you click the house icon, it triggers a `fancybox` popup inside an `iframe` from a cross domain. After further investigation, it turns out the slideshow is *inside* the iframe, which is *inside* the fancybox:

```
$a_link = 'onclick="parent.postMessage(\''.$my_URL.'\', \'*\');"';
```

But after a couple seconds (I guess when the second slide loads) this error appears:

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access

Why does this happen? This used to work until the company changed the slider. Is the `iframe` code triggering the error? The fancybox? The jQuery?

Here is the inspector error:

> `GET http://mesvideos.ca/previsite/%7B%22width%22:300,%22height%22:600,%22startT…ss%22:%22ads-box-inner%22}],%22class%22:%22ads-box%22},%22dummyId%22:true}
>   500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: What is your $my_URL looks like?

Comment: Please link console errors and as much as possible, but I think error comes for a CORS violation, refer to this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Maybe there's a problem with your js files? I'm just guessing. The console said that `progressJs is not defined` and that `Forbidden You don't have permission to access` is maybe have something to do with the file (or whatever) permission of data from the cross domain?